# Internet Explorer 8 not saving cookies from my local dev version

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8, session-cookies

Looking at my website in IE8 in windows XP, cookies work fine.  But, when i connect to my local dev version over the local network, it's not saving cookies.  I'm connecting via an entry in my c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

I'm not that familiar with the intricacies of IE8's security settings.  Could there be something that the live site does, which the local version doesn't, which means the local version is failing some security test and thus not getting its cookies saved?  IE8 is on the default "Medium-High" security setting.  I've tried changing it to "Medium" (the lowest) and get the same problem.

When i say it's not saving the cookies, i mean that i'm looking in the IE8 dev tools/Cache/View Cookie Information page, and it's totally empty (apart from the site url) - there's no cookies saved at all.

Hoping to get some pointers on this, i don't really know where to start trying to fix it.

thanks, max

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out - the hostname i was using had an underscore in it.  When i changed it to a hyphen it worked fine.

thanks for reading!